# Snow Leopard Server SUS Proxy Problems

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, asus

We are really struggling to get our SnoLo server's SUS to contact the Apple update servers - for some reason SUS does not use the system proxy settings - Apple have a work around (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3099) whereby you enter your proxy settings in the swsync plist.

However this doesn't work for us and it wasn't a problem with our 10.5 servers either.

In the KB article Apple helpfully suggests that we reconfigure our firewall rules to allow the server to have direct internet access, amazingly the guardian of our firewall rules is not so keen on the idea!

Comment: If you're certain you saved the file correctly (.plist and not .txt) and that it is trying to use the proxy there's not much else to do.  Perhaps watching the traffic with some custom firewall rules to log it?

Comment: File has been saved just fine - trying to make sense of TCP dump at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Authoxy](http://www.hrsoftworks.net/), I was able to trick ASUS into updating using our proxy...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to open up a tunnel outside of the network and try to use it as a SOCKS proxy.  From [the documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3923):

> Authenticated proxy servers are not
>   supported by the synchronization
>   module, which means updates will not
>   be mirrored by the server. While the
>   synchronization module may work with
>   non-authenticated and transparent
>   proxy servers, Apple recommends that
>   the Software Update server have direct
>   access to the public Software Update
>   servers listed above.

Comment: What makes it more annoying is we are not even using an authenticated proxy server.  Furthermore our Windows 2008 WSUS is more than happy with using our proxy.